# Include package json dependencies for npm install global

Tags: node.js

I only know npm install locally particular plugin into the dependencies object in the package.json. Been doing npm install -g on many packages manually, but how do I include it inside the package.json?

eg. my current package:

```
  {
    "name": "mypackage",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "react": "16.8.3",
  }
}
```

To include my global install modules into mypackage

```
├── expo-cli@3.0.8
├── npm@6.9.0
├── npm-check-updates@3.1.20
├── react-devtools@4.1.0
├── react-native-cli@2.0.1
└── typescript@3.6.3
```

Comment: without the `-g` flag? but remember to `npm init` your project first.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project root directory and execute,

```
npm install your-package-name
```

Or you can put the `package-name` manually in your `package.json` file and run,

```
npm install
```

> But your package is already globally installed on your machine.

When you install an npm package, globally, using `npm install -g my-package`, then the package is globally available in your machine. You can use it anywhere in your machine.

But without global flag `-g` when you install a package, it only available inside the project scope.

So when a package is available globally, you do not need to install it in your project scope. It's a code redundant.

Answer (score 0):

just type

$ npm install name-of-the-dependency

This is going to install the dependency in the package.json

Answer (score 0):

The package will be added to your `package.json` when you install it from the project directory without `-g`

```
npm install --save package
```

you can also save the developer dependencies by

```
npm install --save-dev package
```

when you want to download a package for developers, such as grunt, gulp, then use this option

when you are distributing your code to production, these dependencies will not be available.

If you want to include packages like `angular-cli`  you can install it as normal package and access it by referring the path inside the `node_modules`. like `node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate with the guidance guys, just updated my question. So to add my global modules into mypackage gonna be like as per below?

```
{
  "name": "mypackage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "expo-cli": "3.0.8",
    "npm": "6.9.0",
    "npm-check-updates": "3.1.20",
    "react-devtools": "4.1.0",
    "react-native-cli": "2.0.1",
    "typescript": "3.6.3"
  }
}
```